# How to display a sorted subarray's key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm relatively new to arrays so bear with me. Situation:
a = 1
b = 3
c = 5

1st question: How do I echo the largest value's key: "c" to the page?
2nd question: In array_multisort($count, SORT_DESC, $elecCondSort); below, why doesn't it work if I remove $elecCondSort from the parameter?

Not sure if my code is the best approach (please if simpler solution exists).  Please explain any modifications also.

```
$elecCondSort = array(
    array ("Condition" => "New", "Count" => 5),
    array ("Condition" => "Used", "Count" => 3),
    array ("Condition" => "Manufacturer refurbished", "Count" => 1),
);

foreach ($elecCondSort as $key => $row)
{
    $condition[$key] = $row["Condition"]; 
    $count[$key] = $row["Count"]; 
}

array_multisort($count, SORT_DESC, $elecCondSort);

echo $condition[$key].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the max Count value and the label of the condition, you can:

```
$elecCondSort = array(
    array ("Condition" => "New", "Count" => 5),
    array ("Condition" => "Used", "Count" => 3),
    array ("Condition" => "Manufacturer refurbished", "Count" => 1),
);

$maxValue = 0;
$labelMaxValue = '';
foreach ($elecCondSort as $item) {
   $labelMaxValue = ($item['Count']>$maxValue) ? $item['Condition'] : $labelMaxValue;
   $maxValue = ($item['Count']>$maxValue) ? $item['Count'] : $maxValue;
}

echo $labelMaxValue;
echo $maxValue;
```

i don't really understand how you want to sort the array, but this code should do it for the max value.

Comment: Thanks Leanyo. That's an elegant way of finding out the max value.  I need to display the name of that value instead.  In this case, it'd be "New." I figure out the solution with "echo $elecCondSort[0]["Condition"]."  Do tell if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: i am not sure about how your entire app works, but i just updated the code so it can retrieve not only the max value, but the label "Condition" too